# How do you pull a certain version of the code in TFS 2013 from within Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit, visual-studio-2013

I need to take a look at the code as of a certain version (commit).  I'm using the Team Explorer tab in Visual Studio 2013.  It has stuff for fetch, push, pull, commit, but I don't see any way to get a certain version of code from the repository.

Suppose I wanted to take a look at the Master branch and work with a snapshot of the code from 2 months ago?  How would I go about doing that?

Also, how do I view commits that have occurred on a specific branch that have been pushed?

Are the above things not available from inside of Visual Studio?  If not, where are they available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the things you listed above you can't do through the GUI yet, but all of them are available through the command line. The key point it that this is really just a git repo, so all of the normal git commands work. You could even use a different git GUI if you wanted.

If you need a good git reference I suggest: http://gitref.org/